# How to upload JSON file to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've a large JSON file, containing a lot of data. I want to upload it to firebase, but obviously can't enter everything one by one. Can someone please tell me exactly how can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Firebase accepts only JSON data. you have to convert your csv to json file first before you push data to firebase.

Comment: @VinayHegde ya. I'm sorry, it is a JSON file. I've editted. Can you please tell me how to proceed with the file?

Comment: You can check this : https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-import , in that repo you can find firebase-import.js . Use that file for uploading.

Comment: @VinayHegde I was trying to import the JSON file but I am getting this error(image attached)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_XyMG_77_SMJ5HcvOGdg_ULxpfGMq-jQ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a super easy to use IMPORT button in the firebase console. Open your browser, go to your Firebase console->Three Dots on the right->Import JSON.

Important to note that when importing, whichever node you have selected in your Firebase database will be overwritten, so make sure you don't have  your root node selected - create a child node and then do your import.

It does need to be a properly formatted JSON file - there are a number of online sites that will check the validity of the file. One file we were trying to import had a missing key - after not finding it while scanning we copy and pasted it into one of the sites and quickly found the issue - so the short story there is your nodes needs to have unique keys to be imported.

[image]

Comment: Programmatically? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401731/import-json-file-from-firebase-admin-sdk

Comment: Is this still an option?

Comment: @BerryBlue For sure! It's still there in the Firebase console for the Real Time Database.

Comment: I cannot find it for firestore though.

Comment: @xinthose Firestore does not offer an import option unfortunately; the Firestore backend is much more complex vs the Realtime Database. I wish it has that feature! If you need to import data, you will have to craft a small app to do that.

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering: there is no option to import it in Firestore (at the moment), you have to do it programmatically.

Here is what I came up with after a lot of search (in my React project).

I added this code next to the Firestore database setup.
Basically you just loop through your data and add each item 1 by 1.

Beware : it seems that there is an (unknown to me) limited number of additions possible at once so I had to split the thing by adding some condition every 100 items.

```
...

const db = admin.firestore();

myStuff.forEach((obj, index) => {
  if(index <= 100) { // manually change this condition to bypass limitations
    db.collection("myCollection")
      .add({
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.name,
      })
      .then(function (docRef) {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      });
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.