# Import to Firestore database JSON file with Geographical point values

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I am trying to import a JSON file with the type of data as in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqHZe.png).

I am trying to understand how to structure the JSON file in order that Firestore recognizes that those are geopoint values.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: How will you be uploading your data?
Will it be uploaded to Firebase programatically or will you import the JSON file to Realtime Database as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54160031/13171940)?

Comment: @RogelioMonter I wanted to upload data to Firestore database with geo point values, I finally did it using a Pyhton program that I created