# How to add 2000+ lines of text in firebase real-time database but faster

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2000 quotes lines  in the word file but I don't want to add all this manually because it will take a lot of time

here is how the database looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1rzQ.jpg

is there any fast way to add all this data
here is the word file https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f3E1sTyA9Mt1_z7K_21IpyFYdKedDRQI/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117337378540666660100&rtpof=true&sd=true if you want to have a look
right now I have 50+ quotes in it but I'm adding up to 2000 , just go through the word file and the database image so u can get a clear picture of how I want to store quotes in firebase

Comment: Have you tried to create a JSON file and upload it to the Firebase Console?

Comment: no i dindt i dont know how to do it , im begneir in firebase

Comment: @Player91 You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54160031/19144006) to learn about JSON uploading :)

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/v57p60/how_can_i_add_a_2000_quotes_line_in_firebases/

Comment: Hey thanks a lot brother , but tbh i don't how do write my qoutes in json format , please can you give a refrence or if have seen the word file and how i want to store the data in firebase can you tell how do I do it

Comment: The bottleneck is not primarily reading these lines and adding them in the DB but rendering and displaying them on the device. Especially as for quotes you never need real-time behavior. Also the quotes in your format are not really objects with several properties but just strings, the authors and the quote itself could be separated though. If you have a javascript page browser, a table sorter or other features, then the load of 2000 quotes might be the bottleneck for the client device, no matter where or how fast the data came from.

Comment: It could be even considered to read the quotes just from a file without adding them to the database, if you never save additional properties in the corresponding table. Word-files are certainly not the best format for it, a simple text- or json-file would be better,  but as I said above: this is not the bottleneck in any app that is rendering these quotes.

Comment: Saving things in the database gives you access to a clear defined security layer though. How well any security related aspects are covered in the end depends on your app, but saving data in files might open a security hole that you didn't consider or never monitor regularly. Also server based page-browsers might be easier to use / implement when the data come from the database. If all data are sent at once to the client and rendered there with a page-browser then there are no server based page browsers though.